# Firebase - How to know there is crash to send?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

case : User with occasional internet access[low speed]. Crash happened.

question : How from app side know that there is something to send or was successfully sent[callback] ? (to inform user that he have to connect to the internet.)

btw: How long will firebase keep crash info to send?(are they queuing and accumulating?)

Comment: For how the information is kept and for how long, you might want to check this video: https://youtu.be/XrltP8bOHT0?si=kRxoZL873o2P0QFx&t=1109